# Open Standard for parking signage data (universal)

Tags: uses-of-open-data, parking

keen to get feedback on a lightweight open JSON based standard for the depiction of parking sign/restriction data.  The focus would be to digitally represent any parking sign anywhere in the world.

https://github.com/whooshka/restrictiondataspec/

This has had initial feedback from some government councils in Melbourne, Australia.  At the moment, pretty much all parking restriction datasets are widely divergent.  This effort should help us to build tools to a common standard.

Please do provide feedback and comments to the team so this standard can start to serve communities and useful tools can be built.